# How to automatically choose an option on an actionSheet in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)sender {

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select the operation to proceed?"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Create", @"Update", @"Duplicate", nil] ;
            [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}
```

Automatically choose cancel if nothing is selected; based on a timer e.g. 5 seconds then boom cancel?

UIActionSheet not UIAlertController due to me wanting to make iOS 7.1 compatible binaries

Comment: I guess if u click outside, it will dismiss itself

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[self.actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]
                             animated:YES];
```

Or for example:

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)sender {

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select the operation to proceed?"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Create", @"Update", @"Duplicate", nil] ;
            [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
      [self performSelector:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) withObject:actionSheet afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)dismissActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{
   if(actionSheet){
      [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]
   }
}
```

Comment: The above broke the actionSheet; it said I hadn't declared actionSheet although I have:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> in header

Comment: Edited above question wanted result is a timer.

Comment: @MANICX100, just save a reference to the actionSheet to a property of the ViewController.

Comment: @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActionSheet *actionSheet; (didn't help)

Comment: How can you give the upvote  to this answer?Please read the question clearly.

Comment: @user3182143 do enlighten me on how I haven't answered the question.

Comment: @MANICX100 you need a strong reference read here about memory management options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559676/how-do-uialertview-or-uiactionsheet-handle-retaining-releasing-themselves-under